# Can the IBM PCjr be upgraded to support the better features of the Tandy 1000?

Tags: ibm-pc, ibm-pcjr, tandy-1000

It is well known that the `IBM PCjr` was a commercial failure and that the `Tandy 1000` series of computers not only matched the features of the PCjr (other than maybe the wireless keyboard), it also provided more features.  Such as better graphics and a sound chip built in.

I don't know off the top of my head how much "better" the Tandy's graphics were over the PCjr, but I don't believe the PCjr had any audio except a speaker for beeps.

So, my question is, was it possible to upgrade the PCjr to the same level of graphics and sound as the Tandy 1000?

**EDIT**

I was wrong about the sound abilities of the PCjr.  It did have audio built in.  But I'm not sure how it compared to Tandy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PCjr supports three-voice audio; the Tandy 1000 copied that so running games in Tandy mode should work on a PCjr too. Some games might need a [small program](http://www.brutman.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=99) to switch to three-voice audio on first.

Both the PCjr and Tandy 1000 support 16-colour graphics in 320×200, but many games which run on Tandy machines don't work on the PCjr. There is a simple enough hardware modification to make a PCjr Tandy-compatible though; the Internet Archive still [has the details](https://web.archive.org/web/20140504205810/http://vintagemashups.net/2011/12/ibm-pcjr-tandy-1000-graphics-mod/).

Going beyond Tandy compatibility, there are quite a few useful upgrades for the PCjr, including in particular replacing the 8088 CPU with a NEC V20. Nerdly Pleasures has [details](http://nerdlypleasures.blogspot.fr/2014/03/ibm-pcjr-upgrades.html).

Nerdly Pleasures also has a [detailed article on the differences between the PCjr and Tandy 1000](http://nerdlypleasures.blogspot.fr/2012/06/ibm-pcjr-and-tandy-1000-games.html). Apart from the slight differences in graphics handling, the major difference is the memory handling: the PCjr was designed for 128 KiB, whereas the Tandy 1000 was designed for more. The PCjr can be expanded but it retains quirks in its memory layout...